# YouTube Sdk : Remove Ads from YouTubePlayer

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I have used YouTube sdk for playing YouTube video in it. I want to remove ads in youtube player. Is it possible to remove ads from YouTubePlayer.

I have used `"player!!.cueVideo(Url)"`

I have used [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications) sample code for YouTube sdk.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method straight from the Youtube API for this as can be seen in the [methods reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/). You'll have to rely on other alternatives like Adblock Extension or mini-hacks from this [SO post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18453/how-can-i-disable-the-advertisements-shown-before-youtube-videos).